# How to extract single key and convert to class using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

Here is my json:

```
{  

   "timestamp":"04295d4f-2a6f-4a38-a818-52108cbdc358",
   "lastFullSyncDate":null,   
   "ftpInfo":null,      
   "listingInfo":{        
      "itemID":"110179365615",
      "itemTitle":"test",
      "itemPrice":"88.2235294117647",      
      .......
      ....
      .....
   }
}
```

I have a java class named `listingInfo`  was trying to use gson to convert the string with the key of `listingInfo` to the class, but i'm getting nulls for all the vars.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.fromJson(json, ListingInfo.class);
```

While trying to convert to the part class which contains the time stamp and etc i dot get the vars but the `listingInfo` is null inside

Is it possible to get into the nested key and only convert him to the class?

Comment: Can you please show the ListingInfo class to?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by parsing whole json tree and then extracting the nested key

```
String json = ...; //your json string
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement  element = new JsonParser().parse(json); //parse to json tree
JsonElement listingElement = element.getAsJsonObject().get("listingInfo"); // extract key
ListingInfo listingInfo = gson.fromJson(listingElement, ListingInfo.class);
```